# CSS graphic manipulations - connecting dynamic Divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, graphics

I'm trying to connect a number of dynamically generated content divs with a line using CSS. Every three divs a line would curve, attach an arrow image to its ending and then split the contents with an extra line.

Does anyone here have any idea how this could be achieved? (I have very limited (nearly no) CSS3 experience, but I'm assuming it might be capable of something similar)

I've tried adding a fixed-height element in between the divs, but that would have to be terribly hardcoded and is probably not a viable solution.

Keep in mind that the "arrow" can be a simple image, so drawing that is not the issue here. It's the "green line" representation that I'm unable to do.

A graphical representation of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be doable by mixing the following:

[pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

[:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Here's a simple code that should get you going (note it's just a concept and if you want more before/after elements you should probably add them as list elements children):

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

ul li:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -11px;
    width: 11px;
    height: 5px;
    background: green;
}

li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -11px;
    width: 11px;
    height: 5px;
    background: green;
}

li:nth-child(3n+1) {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    clear: right;
}

li:nth-child(3n+1):before {
    content: ''; <!-- possibly your image url -->
}
```

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/bartkarp/nd39pwh3/

Feel free to ask if you've got any questions or something is not clear enough :)